# fasb() cannot find anything on this function

Tags: c++

I am looking at some legacy C++ code that I was handed a few days ago and I came across the following line:

```
double penaltySum=0.
double logDet = log(jacDetPtr[i]);

penaltySum += fasb(logDet);
```

I looked throughout the sources and I cannot find any definition for this function. Additionally, a google search turned up nothing.

If I was to take a guess, I would think this has the effect of accumulation only if `logDet` is finite.

Has anyone else come across this function? Could this be used across platforms?

The code use can be found here: https://sourceforge.net/p/niftyreg/git/ci/master/tree/reg-lib/cpu/_reg_localTrans_jac.cpp#l1321

Comment: Are you actually asking about `std::fabs`? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs

Comment: Curious — could it be a typo for `fabs()`?  Otherwise, it is not a standard function in C (C11).  But the typo theory runs into problems on the basis that the code compiled and runs, so some system must have provided the function.  The code is not inherently portable because it uses a non-standard function.  Good luck finding what that function does.

Comment: Nope. It really is spelled as `fasb`. I thought initially that it was fabs as well..

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The thing is it does compile and run! I also cannot see anything in the included headers

Comment: what do you mean "cannot find any definition"? pretty much any IDE nowadays can "go to definition"/"go to declaration"

Comment: You're probably going to have to dive into the documentation of the systems on which it was originally produced and ran, and find out what the function does on those systems and where it was provided.  It's hard to guess from the name what it might be doing that isn't what `fabs()` would do.  Is this the only reference to it in the code, or are there others?  Could it be that this source file is no longer used and doesn't need to be migrated?  (Google doesn't help: FASB is the Financial Accounting Standards Board, and gets top billing.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Found out it is part of an open source project. Here is the code: https://sourceforge.net/p/niftyreg/git/ci/master/tree/reg-lib/cpu/_reg_localTrans_jac.cpp#l1321 
I will email the authors.

Comment: That's C++ code; the C tag should be removed from the question.  The function appears twice, but each time it is in one branch of `#ifdef _USE_SQUARE_LOG_JAC` (the one where that is undefined).  The use of the leading underscore is dubious but beyond your control (it is in a namespace reserved for the C++ implementation).  However, it appears you need to define `_USE_SQUARE_LOG_JAC` so that the square of the logarithm is added.  Superficially, it appears that `fasb()` is a way of squaring a floating point (`double`) value.

Comment: A Google search on the term `_USE_SQUARE_LOG_JAC` shows just 3 entries (for me, just now).  The summary info of two of the entries shows `#define _USE_SQUARE_LOG_JAC`, which agrees with my suggestion that you should define it too.  Ideally, it would be autoconfigured.  Looking in the project history for that term might enlighten you about the alternative `fasb`.

Comment: Another item: check that you're using the most recent version of the code.  The project is moderately 'alive'; there are commits from March 2018, and signs of activity in 2017 and 2016 too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Nope from the core logic of the code it seems that if `_USE_SQUARE_LOG_JAC` else use absolute value, everywhere else where `#ifdef _USE_SQUARE_LOG_JAC` the choice is between square and abs value, hence the conclusion fasb is a typo and is actually fabs. The reason the code compiles is that of line 14 `#define _USE_SQUARE_LOG_JAC` remove this line and you will get compile time errors

Comment: Probably the alternate branch of the `#ifdef` was never actually tested.

Comment: @SiddharthChabra: You've looked at more and different code from me — you might well be right, though.  It is at least plausible.

Comment: @SiddharthChabra The code does compile. I have to try and load it with a decent IDE, so that I can dig into it but maybe this is some specialist platform thing and could be that due to the define the code never ran.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler refer line 452 1556 and 1704

Comment: @SiddharthChabra: See also line 14 :D

Comment: @Luca since _USE_SQUARE_LOG_JAC is defined in line 4 you can safely ignore this fuction. If you really want to be certain i suggest changing it to fabs as the intest is to find absolute value in the rest of the code where _USE_SQUARE_LOG_JAC is not defined

Comment: @NeilButterworth It is definitely possible and probably the most probable thing.

Comment: Ahhhh yes. Now I am convinced this is a typo.

So much for testing....

Comment: Don't thank me thank VS2018 the complied code just excluded those instructions altogether which lead me to investigate and deduce this !

Comment: Consider reporting the issue to the people maintaining the project.

Comment: I will try and raise an issue!